# How to get a reference to values queried in hbase shell?

Tags: hbase

Throughout the hbase documentation, I find statements like:

> The same commands also can be run on a table reference. Suppose you had a reference t to table ‘t1’, the corresponding commands would be ...

But I'm unable to find how to get references to objects queried, when I make queries from the hbase shell.

How do you get a reference to a table? More to the point, how do you get a reference to the values received?

Answer (score 1):

While creating a table reference to a table can be obtained by `t = create 'test_table', 'cf'`. Later the table reference can be used to perform scan and various other operations. If the table is already created, reference to a table can be set by `t = get_table 'test_table'`

For more detailed information see the help content printed on executing the command `table_help` in hbase shell